# Perfectly elastic supply

Tags: supply-and-demand, producer-theory

How would you algebraically write a perfectly elastic supply?

Will it be infinite at price = 4? (The choice of the number 4 is completely arbitrary)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's pretty much it for any horizontal or vertical line:

P = p0

Comment: Vertical line wouldn’t be the same. That would be $Q = Q_0$. Because at every price the quantity would be constant